# Identify these hinged barbed bones

Tags: species-identification, bone-biology

My daughter Stella and I found these bones on the shore of Port Phillip Bay, Victoria, Australia.

The smaller, barbed bone is attached by a hinged joint that allows it to move through just over 90 degrees. The photos show it at its two extreme positions.

The photos include an Australian 20 cent coin for scale (29mm diameter).

Can anyone identify what kind of bones these are, and which species they come from?

[image: Bones from different angle]
[image: Bones from different angle]
[image: Bones from different angle]

Comment: Looks like one of the [scorpionfish](http://fishesofaustralia.net.au/home/order/44)es.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is part of a Australian trigger fish skull. check the pictures below, unfortunately someone sawed off most of the spine on the skull photo, but you can see the base of it, it is probably not the exact same species, but it is certainly part of a triggerfish skull. There are a [half dozen species](https://australianmuseum.net.au/balistidae-triggerfishes) in Australia.

[image]

[image]

Cool find.